# using android gradle plugin to run aapt

Tags: android, gradle, aapt

I have a custom gradle build file and i need to run aapt with various params (to extract package names and recompile resources in a custom made resource directory).

For the time being i'm iterating over the directories of ../sdk/build-tools/* and taking the latest dir (most recent).
However i know that there's a gradle android plugin and that it has inside an aapt task or a method to control it.

Can i apply the android plugin and use only the aapt command in my task/ groovy class ?

10x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10x once again stack overflow for the flood of answers i got while all the idiotic questions are being answered...

i didn't find a way to do it, but i use the following a separate gradle file with a class that encapsulate finding the aapt and running it, then i use apply from: 'xxx.gradle'
and in the included file i use ext.aapt= new AaptRunner(); then i can use aapt object in the original build script.

Comment: Care to share your script to find aapt?